# Is it possible to put the a Riemannian metric on $n$-torus such that the sectional curvature is strictly lower than $0$ everywhere?

Tags: riemannian-geometry

If $n = 2$, I know that $T^2$ doesn't have a metric $g$ such that the sectional curvature $k < 0$ everywhere, otherwise,

$$0 = 2 \pi (2 - 2 * 1) = 2 \pi \chi(T^2) = \int_{T^2} k d\sigma < 0$$

from Gauss-Bonnet's theorem, which is a contradiction, but I don't know how to prove this for $n > 2$. I thought maybe use a corollary of Bonnet-Myers' theorem could be used to prove this once that it is used to prove that [the $n$-torus doesn't have a metric $g$ such that the sectional curvature $k > 0$ everywhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337976/torus-with-positive-sectional-curvature). I would like to receive a hint about how to prove that the $n$-torus ($n > 2$) doesn't have a metric $g$ such that the sectional curvature $k < 0$ everywhere.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to Preissmann that can be found in Lee's IRM (p. 357) or Petersen's RG (p. 247):

> **Theorem (Preissmann, 1943).** If $(M, g)$ is a compact manifold of negative
> curvature, then any nontrivial Abelian subgroup of the fundamental group is cyclic (i.e. is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$.). In
> particular, no compact product manifold $M\times N$ admits a metric with negative
> curvature.

And this is from Jurgen Just book (Nonpositive Curvature: Geometric and Analytic Aspects):

> Its fundamental group $\pi_1(\Bbb T^n)$ is $\Bbb Z^n$ . Actually, for any compact Riemannian
> manifold $N$ of nonpositive sectional curvature, the rank of any Abelian subgroup
> of $\pi_1(N)$ is at most $n$, and if the curvature is even negative, its rank is
> precisely $1$ (if the Abelian subgroup is nontrivial) by Preissmann's theorem.
> Since the fundamental group of a manifold of nonpositive curvature cannot
> contain elements of finite order, in the negative curvature case therefore all
> nontrivial Abelian subgroups of $\pi_1(N)$ are isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$.

I think one can use [Bishop and O'Neill theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3842456/272127) to prove same statement but I don't know how!

Answer (score 5):

You can prove this using Milnor's early paper [A note on curvature and the fundamental group](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwijm8WIst7yAhUiKVkFHUI4CYcQFnoECAMQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fprojecteuclid.org%2Fdownload%2Fpdf_1%2Feuclid.jdg%2F1214501132&usg=AOvVaw3736ykRv-HCEtUgLyM1GT2). The theorem there says that if $M$ is a compact Riemannian manifold whose sectional curvature is everywhere negative then the fundamental group $\pi_1 M$ has exponential growth.

But the fundamental group of the $n$-dimensional torus is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z^n$, which has polynomial growth of degree $n$.